# How do I load dictionaries for the spell-checker in Texworks with texlive

Tags: texlive, texworks, spelling, dictionaries

I am using TexLive and editing with TexWorks, on Arch. I would like to use the `en_GB` dictionary, but it is not available in the spellcheck dropdown menu (only the `en_US` is available). However, I have the dictionary installed:

```
[rmlopes@baltra]$ sudo find /usr | grep hunspell.en_GB
/usr/share/hunspell/en_GB.dic
/usr/share/hunspell/en_GB-large.dic
/usr/share/hunspell/en_GB.aff
/usr/share/hunspell/en_GB-large.aff

[rmlopes@baltra]$ sudo find /usr | grep hunspell.en_US
/usr/share/hunspell/en_US.aff
/usr/share/hunspell/en_US.dic
```

The `/usr/share/myspell/dicts` directory contains these dictionaries as well.

What could be wrong here? How can I force the detection of the dictionaries in TexWorks?

Comment: Welcome! Why are you using `sudo` for that? Only use root privileges when you need them. Also, your use of `find` is strange. Why are you piping it through `grep` rather than just using `find`?

Comment: You would probably be best advised to ask this on the appropriate Arch Linux forum, ensuring that you provide a bit more information about what you've investigated and what you've found. But before to check the wiki and search the forums first.

Comment: Have you read the comments at https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/texworks/?

Comment: It's just a shortcut that I like and old habits die hard. I forgot to go through the comments, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer lies in the comments of the [texworks package in the AUR](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/texworks/):

> The list of dictionaries presented in TeXworks is accurate, as far as I can tell. In this screenshot, I have hunspell-en and hunspell-de installed: https://i.stack.imgur.com/dZMES.png
>
> After installing the hunspell-en package, it may look like there are lots of different dictionaries in the /usr/share/myspell/dicts directory, but if you look at where those symlinks point to (/usr/share/hunspell), you'll see that most of them are actually just aliases for the en_GB dictionary. There are only three real dictionaries provided by the hunspell-en package, and **TeXworks ends up displaying en_ZW for the en_GB dictionary** because of the aliases.

The three english dictionaries that are real (not symlinked) are the American (en_US), Canadian (en_CA), and the large version of the British (en_GB-large).

Comment: FYI, the links provided are broken.